# Change varchar to int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a senario i have no idea of how i can solve.

Well

I have database like this example
**`myTable`**

```
ID(int) | Category (varchar(20))
1 | 1029
2 | 2020
3 | 2030
```

All records in Category are numbers but the format is varchar.
I can't change the type from varchar to int.

What i need is in my SQL query convert varchar to int of possible.
Because, i need to do something likes tis

```
SELECT * FROM myTable HERE Category => 1000 AND Category =< 2000
```

How is that possible?

Sorry my written english, but i hope you understand anyway :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a `CONVERT`:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    myTable 
WHERE   Convert(Int, Category) >= 1000 
AND     Convert(Int, Category) <= 2000
```

You could also simplify the query with a `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    myTable 
WHERE   Convert(Int, Category) BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to use an index, I would suggest:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable 
WHERE Category >= '1000' AND Category <= '2000' AND
      LEN(Category) = 4;
```

(The first two conditions can use the index.)

Admittedly, the length condition is rather specific to the values you are comparing to.

I would strongly encourage you to change your data structure.  If you cannot, you can still use a computed column:

```
alter table mytable add category_int as (try_convert(int, category)) persisted;
```

You can then add an index on the computed column:

```
create index idx_mytable_category_int on mytable(category_int);
```

Then the formulation:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable 
WHERE Category_int >= 1000 AND Category_int <= 2000
```

Should work fine.